# How to substitute expression globally with bash bracket substitution syntax?

Tags: bash

I want to use the bash syntax `${var/pattern1/pattern2}` to replace the content of `$var` but for all matching patterns `pattern1` instead of the first one.

```
$ A=aa 
$ echo ${A/a/b}
ba
```

I want to get `bb` instead of `ba`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try this syntax which gives output:

```
$ A=aa 
$ echo ${A//a/b}
bb
```

`${A//a/b}` replaces all the matches of a with b. Whereas, `${A/a/b}` will replace only 1st match of a.

More details about Bash Strings Manipulation can be found [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).